# Usar DISTINCT e SUM na mesma Query

Tags: mysql

Bom Tenho a seguinte query:

```
SELECT
    SUM(a.valor - a.desconto - a.credito + a.frete)
FROM
    pedidos a,
    cadastro b
WHERE
    a.status = '2' 
    AND a.data >= '2019-03-29' 
    AND a.data <= '2019-04-29'
    AND a.id_cliente = b.id 
    AND b.id_cidade = '2378'
```

Ela me retorna o valor de 10.859,95. Esse valor esta correto. Porém preciso recuperar mais alguns dados e para isso montem essa query:

```
    SELECT
    SUM(a.valor + a.frete)
FROM
    pedidos a,
    cadastro b,
    produtos_pedidos c
WHERE
    a.status = '2' 
    AND a.data >= '2019-03-29' 
    AND a.data <= '2019-04-29'
    AND a.id_cliente = b.id 
    AND b.id_cidade = '2378'
    AND a.id = c.id_pedido
    AND c.grupo = '234'
```

O problema e que ele me retorna um valor muito maior, então percebi o erro. Os pedidos estão sendo duplicados, pois em um pedido tenho vários `produtos_pedidos`. 
Como faço para fazer o SUM da tabela pedidos porém sem repetir o ID?

Comment: Seria interessante utilizar alias mais sugestivos do que `a`, `b`, `c`. Por exemplo `p` para `pedidos`, `c` para `cadastro` e `pp` para `produtos_pedidos`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tentou remover a tabela `produtos_pedidos` do `join` e usando-a em um filtro com `EXISTS`?

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(a.valor + a.frete)
FROM
    pedidos a,
    cadastro b
WHERE
    a.status = '2' 
    AND a.data >= '2019-03-29' 
    AND a.data <= '2019-04-29'
    AND a.id_cliente = b.id 
    AND b.id_cidade = '2378'
    and EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
          FROM
              produtos_pedidos c
         WHERE
             c.id_pedido = a.id
             AND c.grupo = '234'
    )
```

Comment: Muito bom, da sua forma funcionou. Mas quero complicar só mais um pouquinho. Supondo que eu tire o `SUM` a resposta vai ser a listagem dos valores, e supondo que eu queria que liste todos os valores e um campo `c.qtd` que esta na `produtos_pedidos` como ficaria a query? Tem como editar sua resposta e colocar essa outro opção?

Comment: Hmm, vejamos...esse campo `valor` da tabela `pedidos` é a soma de algum valor na `produtos_pedidos`?

Comment: Não, eu apenas quero fazer a listagem do campo `valor` que esta na tabela `pedido` e do campo `qtd` que esta na tabela `produtos_pedido`